# TWA not working, still showing Custom tab URL bar

Tags: android, kotlin, chrome-custom-tabs, trusted-web-activity

Trying to hide the URL bar in debug mode but no hope:-

Followed:

Old Stackoverflow Guide (Answer didn't work for the OP also):
[Is it possible to hide URL bar on Chrome Custom Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54648249/is-it-possible-to-hide-url-bar-on-chrome-custom-tabs)

Followed (Not Working!):
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/trusted-web-activity/integration-guide/

The device is Rooted but I have still enabled #enable-command-line-on-non-rooted-devices, the file at

```
/data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line
```

with

```
_ --disable-digital-asset-link-verification-for-url="https://example.com"
```

but still not working.

I tried to hide the URL bar from Custom Chrome Tab but not working,
followed google's dev guide but still not working.

Comment: It's hard to understand what is wrong without checking the assetlinks file or the app. Are you able to share those?